# XSLT to get the XML from the body of a SOAP message

Tags: xslt, soap

I am trying to figure out how to grab everything, including the XML tags, from the body of a soap message.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
        xmlns:soap="http://soap/envelope/"
    >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="//soap:Body/*">
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to [this SOAP example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP#Example_message) from Wikipedia:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Header></soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <m:GetStockPrice xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock">
            <m:StockName>IBM</m:StockName>
        </m:GetStockPrice>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Outputs the contents of the SOAP body (not including the `body` element itself):

```
<m:GetStockPrice xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock" 
                 xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <m:StockName>IBM</m:StockName>
</m:GetStockPrice>
```

Comment: This is awesome but what if i need the xsl to ignore the siap namespaces, cuz sometimes I get a request with soap-env , s , soapenv etc